# Is there a way to stop OpenShift restarting my application when it exits?

Tags: openshift

I want to run an OpenShift application that takes a few hours to run. Once the application finishes (exit 0) I don't want it run again via a restart. I just want to look at the logs to see what it did.

One way of achieving this is for the application to stop itself once it's done processing using the OpenShift API. I'm hoping there is an easier way than this.

The application uses node.js

The use case is I'm running back tests for a trading application. There is no UI to the application. It's just processing historical trades stored in a large file.

Comment: Not sure if you have a OS free account or not but free accounts only allow 5 minutes of processing time at once. Any process that takes over 5 minutes gets killed.

Comment: Thanks for the the tip @fatfantasma. I haven't hit that problem on OpenShift. I have on Cloud9 IDE, though.